# Fetching information from server and assign required data to Spinner using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

How to fetch information from server and assign that data to `Spinner` using retrofit and `Gson` converter?

**Gradle**

```
   dependencies {
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    }
```

**PhP code**

```
<?php

require "con.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_cross";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array('cross'=>$row['school_cross']));
}

echo json_encode ($response);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:background="#d0d0f7"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Firstly get data from the response, which you want to set in spinner. For example, show the list of dates.

```
private ArrayList<String> datesList=new ArrayList<>();
datesList.addAll(response.body().getData());
setDatesSpinner();
```

2.Call `setDatesSpinner` method for setting data in spinner.

```
private void setDatesSpinner() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> datesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_progress_date_list, datesList);
    pro_date_spinner.setAdapter(datesAdapter);
    pro_date_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Api interface 

    public interface ApiFetchCross {
    
        String BASE_URL = "http://www.Example.com/school/";
    
        @GET("fetch_cross.php")
        Call<List<fetch_cross_serialized>> getResponse ();
    }